# SharePoint 2010 Calculated Column with IF AND

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calculated-field

Can someone troubleshoot this SharePoint formula for me? The following SharePoint formula is giving me an error:

```
=if(and([Impact SUM]<=3,[Impact#2s]=0,"LOW", if([Impact SUM]>4,"HIGH","MEDIUM"))
```

It’s based on this Excel formula:

```
=IF(AND(D11<=3,E11=0),"LOW",IF(D11>4,"HIGH","MEDIUM"))
```

I am moving an Excel sheet into a SharePoint list.  The SharePoint field [Impact SUM] is Excel column E "Sum" and [Impact#2s] is Excel column F "#2s"

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the logic of the formula but you are missing a closing ")" after "LOW". See below:

`=IF(AND([Impact SUM]<=3,[Impact#2s]=0,"LOW"), IF([Impact SUM]>4,"HIGH","MEDIUM"))`